# Rails: changing existing association from "Has_many, Belongs_to" gracefully?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, database-design, has-many-through, rails-activerecord

Currently, a User can create a Track(just think of document). Users can also bookmark these tracks. 
I would like to add a Co-Author feature, where many users can edit a single track. How would I change the existing 'User has_many tracks, Tracks belong_to User' relationship, while maintaining the current author?

User.rb:

```
#authors(creates) track
has_many :creations, :class_name => "Track", :foreign_key => "author_id"

#bookmarks track
has_many :track_users
has_many :tracks, :through => :track_users
```

Track.rb:

```
belongs_to :author, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "author_id"

#bookmarked users
has_many :track_users
has_many :users, :through => :track_users
```

Would I just have to create another join table like I did with bookmarking(":through => :track_users"), and use a script to move the authors to the new join table?

Answer (score 1):

you can go with this at least 2 ways

1. keep the author association and just create a join table. you can probably use habtm with this one if you're not planning on adding more attributes on this join table
2. you can drop author_id on track and add an author boolean to the join table.

i prefer the second solution so let's do that.  create a migration that creates the join table and moves the author to the join table

```
def up
  create_table :track_authors do |t|
    t.integer :user_id
    t.integer :track_id
    t.boolean :author, default: false
  end

  add_index :track_authors, :user_id
  add_index :track_authors, :track_id

  # let's call the join table track_authors
  Track.find_each do |track|
    TrackAuthor.create(user_id: track.author_id, track_id: track.id, author: true)
  end
end
```

then in your model, you can do this

```
# track.rb
has_many :track_authors
has_many :authors, through: :track_authors
has_one :author, through: :track_authors, conditions: { track_authors: { author: true } }

# track_author.rb
belongs_to :author, class_name: 'User'
belongs_to :track

# user.rb
has_many :track_authors
has_many :tracks, through: :track_authors
has_many :authored_trackes, through: :track_authors, conditions: { track_authors: { author: true } }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I have a few questions
1. what is the purpose of the boolean? Is that just to identify the original author?
2. what would the user.rb model look like for the new assoc?
3. how would I create the tracks? still be able to use something like "current_user.creations.build?"

Comment: Thank you for the edit :) I'm still a little confused about the "author boolean." Is that to distinguish original authors from co-authors? (maybe so only the original author can delete the track?)

Comment: Also, the conditions for finding the one with "author: true" isn't working. Do I need to maybe specify the belongs_to in the track_author.rb model? 

Here is the gist of where I am currently at https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5027875. I appreciate the help :)